# Unknown Type of Strapi/Gatsby Graphql Query Fragment

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I'm trying to query data within a Strapi Dynamic Zone in Gatsby. In the Graphql Playground I can get this to work, but using the same query in Gatsby I receive the following error in the terminal:

`error  Unknown type "ComponentTextArticleCopy"  graphql/template-strings`

[image]

And my query in `article.js`

```
export const query = graphql`
  query ArticleTemplate($id: String!) {
    strapiArticle(id: { eq: $id }) {
        articleHeader {
            articleTitle
            articleSnippet
          }
          articleContent {
            __typename
            ... on ComponentTextArticleCopy {
              contentCopy
            }
            ... on ComponentImageContentImg {
              imgCaption
            }
            ... on ComponentTextArticleQuote {
              contentQuote
            }
          }
    }
  }
`
```

According to the [Graphql docs](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments), Inline Fragment would seem to be the right approach but clearly I've got something wrong somewhere.

The following query 'works' on Gatsby but tries to resolve for all components:

```
query MyQuery {
  allStrapiArticle {
    edges {
      node {
        __typename
        articleContent {
          contentCopy
          contentQuote
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "allStrapiArticle": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "__typename": "StrapiArticle",
            "articleContent": [
              {
                "contentCopy": null,
                "contentQuote": null
              },
              {
                "contentCopy": "What a great city Gothenburg is.  We even took a trip out to the archipelago. ",
                "contentQuote": null
              },
              {
                "contentCopy": null,
                "contentQuote": null
              },
              {
                "contentCopy": null,
                "contentQuote": "You must visit at have fika"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: what about gatsby? playground, docs?

Comment: ... gatsby **fragments** docs?

Comment: Can you create a Sandbox? It's difficult to guess what's going on without making some trials

Answer (score -2):

Deleting Cache folder and running again worked for me.

Comment: Just to help fill in the gaps for people new to Strapi, can you specify where the Cache folder is located?